# Update Laravel4 pivot table from multiselect

Tags: laravel-4

I am having issues getting a pivot table to sync from a multiselect item in a form.

Form

```
<div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('resources[]', 'Resources:', array('class'=>'col-md-2 control-label')) }}
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::select('resources[]', $allr, $task->resources->lists('id','title'), array('multiple')) }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller

```
public function update($id)
    {
        $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Task::$rules);
        //return $input;
        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            $task = $this->task->find($id);
            $task->update($input);
            $task->resources()->sync(array(1,2,3));

            return Redirect::route('tasks.index');
        }

        return Redirect::route('tasks.edit', $id)
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
    }
```

The form autopopulates nicely. Once submitted this is the value of resources[]

["2","3"]

The error I get is...

> preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while
>   replacement is an array

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by Laravel attempting to put the resources array into an existing field rather than updating the Pivot table. I have removed the resources array from the Input that is passed to the Task Model and it works.